# jQuery .text() length behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have my HTML coded as follows;

```
<div class="welcomeText">
<ul>       
<li><span<%=Some Java Code%></span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Also there is a Javascript code called after document is ready which has the following line;

```
var welcomeLen = $(".welcomeText span").text().length;
```

Now if I want to update my HTML code inside li as follows;

```
<li><span><span class="firstNameWithEllipses"><%=Some Java Code%></span></span>
```

i.e. I want to add a new span element with class="firstNameWithEllipses"

The issue that I am facing is that the JS calculation for welcomeLen changes if I add the above HTML code.

I am not quite sure how the text().length works as it returns the following values for the 2 separate cases;
When rendered as

```
<span>Hello, StudentFname87654 from Functional!</span>
```

it returns 41
&
When rendered as

```
<span>Hello, <span class="firstNameWithEllipses">StudentFname87654</span> from Functional!</span>
```

it returns 58

How do I ensure that the welcomeLen remains the same even if I add any HTML code inside the span ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your selector matches both `span` elements and returns the text from both. You could have added any element other than a child `span` and you would not have experienced this issue:

```
console.log($(".welcomeText span").text());
//Output: Hello, StudentFname87654 from Functional!StudentFname87654
```

Make your selector more specific. You could, for example, select only `span` elements that are direct children of an `li` that is a descendant of `.welcomeText`:

```
var welcomeLen = $(".welcomeText li > span").text().length;
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPEvV/).

**Update**

If you're interested in *why* this is the case, you can look at the [jQuery source for the `text` method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.3.1/src/core.js#L186). Like most jQuery methods, it iterates over all of the elements in the matched set:

```
var ret = "";
jQuery.each( text || this, function(){ //Iterate over matched set
    jQuery.each( this.childNodes, function(){ //Iterate over children of current element
        if ( this.nodeType != 8 )
            ret += this.nodeType != 1 ?
                   this.nodeValue : //Append text to overall string
                   jQuery.fn.text( [ this ] ); //Get text of descendants
    });
});
return ret;
```

Comment: Thx a lot for that...I did not quite understand how it returns for both spans...like how that calculation happens....But anyways I am actually using the JS code across multiple HTMLs and the new span element is added only for 1 html...So how do I ensure that the existing thing would also work if I update the selector to what you have shown ?

Comment: The selector I have used will work for your original example too. It simply looks for a `span` element that is a child of an `li`, which is the case in both of your examples.

Comment: @testndtv - If you are interested in why it returns the text for both, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thx a lot...So it is kind of considering the 2 spans seperately and adding for the final result...

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what it does. It loops over all the `span` elements matched by the selector (which is 2), gets the text of each and builds up a string containing the text from all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var welcomeLen = $(".welcomeText span").not(".firstNameWithEllipses").text().length;
```